# POST hangs on certain install media

Tags: boot, usb, debian, bios, openbsd

I'm trying to install OpenBSD 5.7 on a laptop. I have a USB drive that I am using for the installation media. When I plug in the USB drive with OpenBSD on it, the POST process hangs indefinitely. When I remove the same USB drive, put the Debian 8 live cd on it and reboot, it can boot to Debian just fine.

Conversely, I can put the USB drive with OpenBSD on it in a different computer and boot to the OpenBSD installer without any issue.

How could the POST process even care what is on the USB drive? What exactly is going on here?

Laptop is Dell Inspiron 1501.

Thanks!